# parameters on the basis of which a particular n-tier architecture is chosen

Tags: architecture, n-tier-architecture

What are the parameters on the basis of which a particular n-tier architecture is chosen for an application.

Answer (score 0):

Architecture (in general, not only n-tier) is chosen basing on a set of quality attributes required for a particular application/system. The list of attributes differs slightly in each of the architectural frameworks, most of them however is focused around:

End User's view

- Performance
- Availability
- Usability
- Security

Developer's view

- Maintainability
- Portability
- Reusability
- Testability

Business Community view

- Time To Market
- Cost and Benefits
- Projected life time
- Targeted Market

In addition, in most cases there are some strictly technical/infrastructural concerns involved, like legacy systems.

You can find some helpful information in this article about [quality attributes](http://www.softwarearchitectures.com/go/Discipline/DesigningArchitecture/QualityAttributes/tabid/64/Default.aspx).